# Ubuntu:: ./program: Permission Denied

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

Firstly, my problem is similar to this: [Ubuntu says "bash: ./program Permission denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960689/ubuntu-says-bash-program-permission-denied)

However, I feel the need to further clarify.

When I compile my program using:

```
gcc -c file.c -o file
```

and run

```
./file
```

I get this error:

```
bash:./file: Permission denied
```

When I use

```
chmod u+x file
```

and then run

```
./file
```

I get this error:

```
bash: ./file: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

However, when I compile using

```
gcc file.c -o file <br/>
```

My program runs perfectly well using

```
./file
```

Can someone point out what is the problem with using the `-c` argument with `gcc`?

Comment: So, did you read the gcc documentation? What `-c` does? What did you not understand? Did you search first for it? If not: what other research effort did you do before asking?

Comment: And BTW, GCC documentation is here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `gcc --help` to see some help.

```
-c                      Only run preprocess, compile, and assemble steps
```

This means that, when run with this option, GCC doesn't *link* the executable with any (even system) libraries.

In short, to run a program, the OS needs a starting point, which is located in some system library. Since in your case GCC isn't linking the executable with *anything*, the OS doesn't know *how to run the file*, where to start.