# script is not an en executable regular file

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I've created a script using `sudo nano yellowfin` and then put in below code and saved it, however when i try to run it it gives me the error that `script yellowfin is not an executable regularfile, skipped`

code in file

```
#!/bin/bash
# USAGE: start|stop
#
case "$1" in
start)
echo "Starting Yellowfin."
/opt/yf/appserver/bin/startup.sh
;;
stop)
echo "Stopping Yellowfin."
/opt/yf/appserver/bin/shutdown.sh
;;

*)
echo “Yellowfin Service”
echo $”Usage: $0 {start|stop}”
exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

then i update with

```
 sudo update-rc.d yellowfin defaults
```

Comment: Have you remembered to [change the mode bits](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) to make the script executable?

Comment: `chmod +x yellowfin`

Comment: now i've done that and get `script missing LSB tag and overrides`

Comment: And googling that error message gets you ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu says "bash: ./program Permission denied"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960689/ubuntu-says-bash-program-permission-denied)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make sure your script is executable with `chmod +x yellowfin` and to fix `script missing LSB tag and overrides` add this at the top of your bash script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          example
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Example initscript
# Description:       This file should be used to construct scripts to be
#                    placed in /etc/init.d.  This example start a
#                    single forking daemon capable of writing a pid
#                    file.  To get other behavoirs, implemend
#                    do_start(), do_stop() or other functions to
#                    override the defaults in /lib/init/init-d-script.
### END INIT INFO
```