# Permission denied when trying to run binary executable

Tags: bash, file-permissions, acl, nfs, selinux

I'm getting Permission denied error when trying to run a binary executable, and I can't figure out why.

```
[me@me bin]$ ./alpha
-bash: ./alpha: Permission denied
```

(root is able to run)

mod is `777`. I suspected selinux, but `setenforce 0` doesn't help. File context is `system_u:object_r:default_t:s0`.

The file was first installed on NFS, shared with another server, then moved to local storage. After this, I started to get the error. On the other server, where the file is still on NFS, it runs without any problem.

This is getfacl result, so I believe this is not ACL problem:

```
# file: alpha
# owner: ****
# group: ****
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

What can cause the Permission denied? Where can I look for logs?

Comment: Check the extended permissions on the file with getfacl.

Comment: Can you show the actual command and full error message?

Comment: Make sure the filesystem which the executable was copied to allows files to be executed (there's a mount flag)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have modified the question.

Comment: Those who voted to close as off-topic: can you please write in comment which is the better forum for this?

Comment: Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960689/ubuntu-says-bash-program-permission-denied