# Bitbucket pipeline to deploy Google App Engine using shell

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bitbucket-pipelines

I am creating bitbucket pipeline in which I am using shell script which will take environment name.
Based on environment name I am deploying the code to different environments.

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          # Install Google Cloud SDK
          - export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
          # Google Cloud SDK is pinned for build reliability. Bump if the SDK complains about deprecation.
          - SDK_VERSION=127.0.0
          - SDK_FILENAME=google-cloud-sdk-${SDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
          - curl -O -J https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/${SDK_FILENAME}
          - tar -zxvf ${SDK_FILENAME} --directory ${HOME}
          - export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin
          # Install Google App Engine SDK
          - GAE_PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/google_appengine
          - export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${GAE_PYTHONPATH}
          - python scripts/fetch_gae_sdk.py $(dirname "${GAE_PYTHONPATH}")
          - echo "${PYTHONPATH}" && ls ${GAE_PYTHONPATH}
          # Install app & dev dependencies, test, deploy, test deployment
          - pip --quiet install -r requirements.txt -t lib/
          - echo "key = '${GOOGLE_API_KEY}'" > api_key.py
          - python test_main.py
          - echo ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET} > client-secret.json
          - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file client-secret.json
          - ./deploy.sh dev service-test here
```

I am getting following error:

```
    + ./deploy.sh dev test-service
bash: ./deploy.sh: Permission denied
```

Comment: Does the userid executing the pipeline have read and execute permissions for `./deploy.sh` (and read/execute permissions for all its ancestor directory path)?

Comment: @DanCornilescu, how to check and give read/execute permission to deploy.sh on bitbucket pipeline ?

Comment: From its path it appears to exist in your app dir. `ls -l ./deploy.sh`, `chmod u+x ./deploy.sh`. An alternative is to ignore it's not executable and run it explicitly from bash: `bash ./deploy.sh dev service-test here`.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I am using bitbucket pipeline to deploy on Google App Engine. How can change the mode in the path ?

Comment: I'm not saying to do it in bitbucket, I mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960689/ubuntu-says-bash-program-permission-denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add "- bash" before the actual bash script is called. In your case it'd be:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          # Install Google Cloud SDK
          - export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
          # Google Cloud SDK is pinned for build reliability. Bump if the SDK complains about deprecation.
          - SDK_VERSION=127.0.0
          - SDK_FILENAME=google-cloud-sdk-${SDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
          - curl -O -J https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/${SDK_FILENAME}
          - tar -zxvf ${SDK_FILENAME} --directory ${HOME}
          - export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin
          # Install Google App Engine SDK
          - GAE_PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/google_appengine
          - export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${GAE_PYTHONPATH}
          - python scripts/fetch_gae_sdk.py $(dirname "${GAE_PYTHONPATH}")
          - echo "${PYTHONPATH}" && ls ${GAE_PYTHONPATH}
          # Install app & dev dependencies, test, deploy, test deployment
          - pip --quiet install -r requirements.txt -t lib/
          - echo "key = '${GOOGLE_API_KEY}'" > api_key.py
          - python test_main.py
          - echo ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET} > client-secret.json
          - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file client-secret.json
          - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file client-secret.json
          - bash ./deploy.sh dev service-test here
```