# Modified Castlia 3.3 + omnetpp 5.3 on ubuntu- permission denied

Tags: omnet++

I have compiled both castalia 3.3 with its modified version adapted to omnet 5.3 and everything was right but when running simulation using command line

**/Castalia/Simulations/radioTest$ ../../bin/Castalia -c General**

I got this error:

**bash: ../../bin/Castalia : Permission denied**

I added the path to .bashrc and .profile in ubuntu

**export PATH=$PATH:/home/usr/../Castalia/bin**

but still got the same error

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not related to Castalia specifically. You could have searched with "program permission denied" to find the general answer: [Ubuntu says "bash: ./program Permission denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960689/ubuntu-says-bash-program-permission-denied)

Adding Castalia in the path will not fix your problem. The system can find the `Castalia` script fine (you provide the absolute path in the first place). It just can't execute it.

Execute the command below in Castalia's `bin` directory. This will give the right permission to all 3 castalia scripts:

```
chmod u+x Castalia*
```