# Vagrant on init up check if folder exists, else create?

Tags: bash, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

When we want first time run vagrant up, how to check if in project directory exists  synced folders, and if not exists, then create before rest of process go on?

i try with:

```
  config.trigger.before [:up] do |trigger|
    trigger.info = "Create log, tmp, webroot/img folders"
    trigger.run = {path: ".provisioning/before_up.sh"}
  end
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
# before_up.sh

if [ ! -d "logs" ]; then
  sudo mkdir logs
fi

if [ ! -d "tmp" ]; then
  sudo mkdir tmp
fi

if [ ! -d "webroot/img" ]; then
  sudo mkdir webroot/img
fi
```

but have errors

```
==> default: Running triggers before up ...
==> default: Running trigger...
==> default: Create logs, tmp, webroot/img folders
    default: Running local script: .provisioning/before_up.sh
==> default: Trigger run failed
==> default: Permission denied - /Users/me/apps/.provisioning/before_up.sh
```

Comment: It looks like 'before_up.sh' is not executable.  Try running `chmod +x` on it.  See [Ubuntu says “bash: ./program Permission denied”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18960689/4154375) (it's not really Ubuntu-specific).

Comment: This script is just `sudo mkdir -p logs tmp webroot/img`

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, but we have more to do in ```if then``` block.

Answer (score 0):

**here is solution**

at top of Vagrant file add:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p './logs'
FileUtils.mkdir_p './tmp'
FileUtils.mkdir_p './webroot/img'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 # config here
end
```

from ruby documents:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p

> mkdir_p(list, options = {}) click to toggle source Options: mode noop
>   verbose
>
> Creates a directory and all its parent directories. For example,
>
> FileUtils.mkdir_p '/usr/local/lib/ruby' causes to make following
>   directories, if it does not exist.
>
> - /usr
> - /usr/local
> - /usr/local/lib
> - /usr/local/lib/ruby