# unable to execute bash command within ubuntu : permissions denied

Tags: linux, bash, docker, operating-system

unable to execute bash in docker container :ubuntu

this is my bash script (its calling):

```
#!/bin/sh

php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

it in turn calls this script:

```
> #!/usr/bin/env php <?php /**  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.  * See COPYING.txt for license details.  */
> 
> if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
>     echo 'bin/magento must be run as a CLI application';
>     exit(1); }
```

this is the error message :

```
root@a72397092db6:/var/www/html# ./bins/clean
bash: ./bins/clean: Permission denied
root@a72397092db6:/var/www/html#
```

I would like the script to execute . I do have permissions to execute it. 
this is the permission for the directory.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 root   68 Jul 23 14:07 clean
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 root  234 Jul 23 14:07 compile
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 root 6148 Jul 23 14:28 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 root  118 Jul 23 14:07 permissions
```

Comment: This question has many duplicates, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960689/ubuntu-says-bash-program-permission-denied Just googling "bash execute permissions denied" would have lead to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have permissions to execute (`x`) it unless you give them to yourself:

```
chmod +x ./bins/clean
```

You need the permissions to look like this (provided you'll run the script as `root` which you probably will since it's in Docker):

```
-rwxr--r--  1 1000 root   68 Jul 23 14:07 clean
```